# Как в MySQL объединить записи по заданному критерию с дополнительным расчетом?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в которой накапливаются данные (до нескольких сотен записей в секунду). 
Нужно получить в табличном виде сгруппированные значения за заданный интервал времени, например 5 минут.
Другими словами, все записи в пределах 5 минут (причем выровненных по времени от 12:30:00 до 12:34:59) должны быть суммированы по нескольким полям.
На выходе должны получить таблицу со следующими полями:
дата_время, 
суммарный объем,
минимальное значение объема за заданный интервал,
максимальное значение объема за заданный интервал.

В процессе миграции на MySQL с Firebird возникло затруднение как выполнить подобную задачу.
В Firebird это решалось хранимой процедурой, которая вызывалась когда нужно было получить выборку данных сгруппированной по времени. В ней делалась выборка оператором for select ... into ... do проводилась обработка каждой записи выполняя заданную логику.

Насколько я понял, в MySQL в хранимой процедуре нельзя сформировать выборку данных "на лету", а можно вернуть только конкретные значения переменных. (Может я не прав?)

Можно ли как-то сделать подобное в MySQL.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот один из вариантов. Положим, таблица имеет вид `(value, time)`. Фокус в том, чтобы каждому пятиминутному периоду присвоить свой порядковый номер. Тогда группировка записей внутри периода сведётся к банальной группировке по числовому полю.

```
select sum(tt.value) as sum,
       -- Здесь для удобства представления информации получаем из id пятиминутки
       -- UNIX time и переводим его в более удобочитаемый формат
       from_unixtime(tt.min5 * 300) as period
from (
    select t.*,
           -- Здесь мы присваиваем каждой пятиминутке уникальный id.
           -- Для этого мы время из timestamp переводим в UNIX time
           -- (число секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 года)
           -- и делим на 300 (число секунд в 5 минутах)
           floor(unix_timestamp(t.time) / 300) as min5
    from test t
) tt
group by tt.min5
order by tt.min5;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99d5e8/1

Comment: Хороший способ. Минимальное и максимальное значение как получить тоже понятно. Можно ли каким то образом получить первое значение tt.value в этой 5-ти минутной выборки, а также последнее?